Нужна ли запятая перед тире в сложном предложении после цитаты?
Нужна ли эта (выделенная полужирным шрифтом) запятая в этом предложении: "Вероятно, Вам известна знаменитая фраза "И всё-таки она вертится!", — эту фразу когда-то сказал знаменитый учёный Галилео Галилей"? Или, может быть, возможны варианты и с запятой, и без?

В предложениях с указательным местоимением этот возможны оба варианта (тире и единый знак), поэтому надо сделать выбор. В данном случае более уместен единый знак, так как присоединительное значение сочетается с дополнительным пояснительным оттенком:
Вероятно, Вам известна знаменитая фраза "И всё-таки она вертится!", — эту фразу когда-то сказал знаменитый учёный Галилео Галилей.
Цитата здесь является структурным элементом, входящим в состав  предложения, и на выбор знака не влияет. Это приложение: фраза (какая?).
Тема регулируется правилами Розенталя.
§ 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении

Если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения представляет собой присоединительное предложение, перед ней ставится тире (возможно вставить слово это, которое иногда имеется в самом предложении):  Инга была возбуждена, Левшин наблюдал за ней слишком пристально — это бросалось Клебе в глаза (Фед.); Идёт большая вода — это всего интереснее (Горб.); Он всегда любил поболтать — это было мне отлично известно (Кав.); Они расстанутся, они уже расстались — эта мысль ошеломила обоих (Гран.)[20].

§ 46. Запятая и тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении

Запятая и тире ставятся между двумя частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, из которых вторая носит присоединительный характер с каким-либо дополнительным оттенком значения (пояснительным, временным, условно-следственным и др.): Ситанов относится ко мне дружески, — этим я обязан моей толстой тетради, в которой записаны стихи (М. Г.); Нижняя доска обмазывалась коровьим навозом и три раза поливалась водой на морозе, — после этого она делалась как зеркало (А. Т.);

